# Properly rendering stored HTML

Tags: php, regex

A part of my site allows users to create comments in a text box to be stored in an SQL database. Because a lot of people copy/paste things in from word or other places, I have to keep `<p>` and `<br>` tags to keep formatting, and also `<a>` tags to let users create their own links. Everything else gets stripped out. I *was* accomplishing this like so:

```
$text = strip_tags( $text, '<br><a><p>' );
```

But today a user came to me and told me they lost a large portion of their text because they made a arrow `<-` for visual effect. So now I know strip tags removes everything after a `<`.

I can accomplish a similar effect with `preg_replace` like so:

```
preg_replace('/((?!<((\/)?p|br|a))<[^>]*>)/', "", $text);
```

But this still has the downside of only working if the tag spans one line (I think), leaving in html comments and probably a few other things that I'm not aware of. What are my options? Is there a catch all solution? A library I can use? I most work alone so I'm not really aware of industry standards.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are letting users enter HTML tags into the comments textbox?

Comment: Yes, only because people copy paste from other sources and expect the formatting to look the same when it is submitted. Mostly spacing.

Comment: So these users format their text using HTML tags? I would recommend Just HTML encoding input and not allowing users to enter HTML at all. If formatting is a must, you can look into rich text editor controls.

Comment: **I can accomplish a similar effect with preg_replace...But this still has the downside of only working if the tag spans one line (I think)**. Not really because you could use some modifiers to make Regular Expressions in PHP span multiple lines. Consider your Regex but with a Multiline & Case Insensitivity  Flag: `preg_replace('/((?!<((\/)?p|br|a))<[^>]*>)/sim', "", $text);`

Comment: Use a [Markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use html purifier. It help clean the summited html and removes the unwanted codes for example if a user adds a scripts tag that might cause harm to your website (XSS Attack) html purifier before submitting. It also adds or completes html for example a user inputs < strong > gamer ... with out closing the tag, it will close the tag and output cleaner html.

Answer (score 0):

**I can accomplish a similar effect with preg_replace...But this still has the downside of only working if the tag spans one line (I think).** *Not really! You could use some modifiers to make PHP Regular Expressions span multiple lines.* Consider the Example below with Multiline HTML String:

```
    <?php
        // $s IS A MULTILINE HTML SNIPPET CONTAINING THE FOLLOWING HTML TAGS
        // <div>, <a>, <blockquote>, <em>, <strong>, <span>, <br /> 
        $s  = "<div class='one'>
                    <a href='/link.php'>
                        <blockquote>
                            There is real Power in the Hearts of men: not just Power but
                            \"something so much powerful than Power\" that Power itself begs to \"power down\".
                        </blockquote>
                    </a>
                    <p class='lv'>
                        This Power is not in the Head nor in the Intellect nor in the Skills of Man...
                        <em class='em1'>but in the deep recess of the Human Heart...</em>
                        and it speaks volumes yet only very few understand its language -
                        <strong>The Language of Love</strong>
                        - The Greatest Power You can have.... The Power to which nothing is Impossible!!!
                    </p>
                    <br />
                    <span>Do you know this Power? <--</span>
                    <strong>Do you Speak Love???</strong>
                </div>";

        // THIS CONCISE REGEX PATTERN REMOVES ALL HTML TAGS WITHIN THE MULTILINE STRING
        // EXCEPT FOR TAGS LIKE: <a> <p> <br />
        // IT WOULD ALSO LEAVE <- OR <-- OR <------ UNTOUCHED
        $r  = preg_replace("#<(?!\/[ap]|[ap\-]|br).*?>#si", "", $s);
        echo ($r);
```

If you viewed the `Source Code`, You would observe that all HTML Tags except for `<br>, <p>, <a> and Symbols like <--` were stripped out. In effect, the `Source` would look something like this:

```
    <a href='/link.php'>

            There is real Power in the Hearts of men: not just Power but
            "something so much powerful than Power" that Power itself begs to "power down".

    </a>
    <p class='lv'>
        This Power is not in the Head nor in the Intellect nor in the Skills of Man...
        but in the deep recess of the Human Heart...
        and it speaks volumes yet only very few understand its language -
        The Language of Love
        - The Greatest Power You can have.... The Power to which nothing is Impossible!!!
    </p>
    <br />
    Do you know this Power? <--
    Do you Speak Love???
```

Cheers and Good-Luck...

Comment: The `m` modifier here actually isn't being used. The `m` is for `^` and `$`. The `s` is allowing the `.` to include new lines.

Answer (score 0):

If your case is simple as how you showed us in your question, I won't go with external libraries like HTML Purifier.

[`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/strip_tags) function has its own way to determine tags. One way that it doesn't consider a `<` a real tag is when it's followed by an space. By *space* I mean any character between **0x09** to **0x0d** as well as **0x20** (it is how [`isSpace()`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/1c295d4a9ac78fcc2f77d6695987598bb7abcb83/ext/mbstring/oniguruma/enc/mktable.c#L732) internal function works by its call from [`php_strip_tags_ex()`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/string.c#L4729)).

So a workaround could be putting one of those allowed spaces between `<-` characters and then revert it after doing a [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/strip_tags) but you'd better take care of not only a `<` character followed by `-` but any `<` character followed by a `[^a-zA-Z!?\s]` character (a character which is not an alphabet, `!` and `?` marks, `\s` any kind of white-space characters (spaces are fine!))

I'd like to choose my space character to be a carriage-return `\r` which is **0x0D** in hex. That is more specific:

```
$text = preg_replace( "~<\r([^a-zA-Z!?\s])~", "<\1", strip_tags( preg_replace( '~<([^a-zA-Z!?\s])~', "<\r\1", $text ), '<p><a><br>' ) );
```

Answer (score -1):

I can recommend you to encode the data that the user submits and then remove the tags you don't allow. This way you won't remove tags that appear normally on the page.

> Please note that running complex regex expression on big string so not efficient.

Take the input from the user encode it so instead of `<p>` you will save `&lt;p&gt;` and then you can insert it to the page as html so it will render as html but without the actual tags, that way you don't need to remove anything.

You can use `htmlspecialchars(string)` here is an [example](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_htmlspecialchars.asp)

Comment: I mean theres a lot of tags I don't allow, thats why I have a white list instead of a black list. And I would love to avoid using regex, but I'm not sure what else to do.